# Heatmaps with each box represents multiple sources using R

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, heatmap, complexheatmap

I would like to plot heatmaps that are similar to this:
[image]

where there are three rows corresponding to each box. I am thinking about using the ComplexHeatmap package in R but couldn't find an example, any suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: This question should have some sample data. What do you mean by "multiple sources"? This could be done with `facet_grid` in ggplot2 where each facet in the grid is three `geom_tile`s.

Comment: The image I cropped was from a published paper therefore sample data is not available. By 'multiple sources' I mean there are multiple values corresponding to one box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a ggplot2 example. The code after `facet_grid` is fiddling the theme to look more like your example.

```
df <- data.frame(row = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 1e3, replace = TRUE),
                 col = sample(letters[11:20], 1e3, replace = TRUE),
                 segment = sample(1:3, 1e3, replace = TRUE, prob = 1:3))


library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  count(col, row, segment) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = 1, y = segment, fill = scale(n))) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdBu") +
  facet_grid(row~col, switch = "both") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "line"),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jon for your answer! I tried to replicate it however an error occurred: Error in count(., col, row, segment) : unused argument (segment)

Comment: Perhaps you have `plyr` loaded? What if you use `dplyr::count(col, row, segment) %>%` for that row?